# c++ object construction using operator=

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, operator-overloading

I am maintaining the rule of three like this --

```
// actual constructor
stuff::stuff(const string &s)
{
    this->s_val = s[0];
    this->e_val = s[s.length() - 1];
}

// copy constructor
stuff::stuff(const stuff &other)
{
    this->s_val = other.s_val ;
    this->e_val = other.e_val ;
}

// assignment
stuff& stuff::operator=(const stuff &other)
{
    stuff temp(other);
    *this = move(temp); 
    return *this;
}
```

now I can call like this --

```
stuff s1("abc");
stuff s2(s1);
stuff s3 = s2 ; // etc ...
```

Now I am trying to implement a function that will use `operator=` so that I can call like --

```
stuff s;
s = "bcd" ;
```

and I am writing like this --

```
stuff& stuff::operator=(const string &s)
{
    stuff temp(s);
    *this = move(temp);
    return *this;
}
```

but it is giving me segfault. Moreover what should I do if want to call like

```
stuff s = "bcd" ?
```

how do I do that ?

Comment: `*this = move(temp);` is calling the assignment operator you are trying to define.

Comment: i see, so is it making a recursive call ?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: no wait, but my `operator=()` has a `string` argument, not a `stuff`, and then why it is not doing recursive call in `stuff& stuff::operator=(const stuff &other)`?

Comment: Your other `operator=`. The one with the recursive call (unless you have move assignment, but you haven't shown that.) Anyway, do you really need to implement the special member functions? If so, show enough code to prove that you do.

Comment: ok got it, I have fixed it. but how do I overload `operator=` so that I can call like `stuff s4 = "bcd"` ?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread it, disregard my comment.

Comment: Please show a complete example that reproduces the problem. What you have posted [seems OK](http://ideone.com/zuov45).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you assignment operator and copy constructor should look the same :

```
stuff& stuff::operator=(const stuff &other)
{
    this->s_val = other.s_val ;
    this->e_val = other.e_val ;
    return *this;
}
```

you can't define you `=` operator with another `=` operator .
remember, `std::move` doesn't do any special magic, it just turns a variable into somthing that can be cought using move semantics. you still need to define your function as one who deals with r-value-reference in the first place, which you didn't (you dont have any move assignment operator).

in you string-accepting `=` operator , you can use the regular one :

```
stuff& stuff::operator=(const string &s)
{
    *this = stuff(s);
    return *this;
}
```

few more suggestions :
your `this->` is redundent. the compiler knows the variable you're refering is part of `this`.
also , the lines:

```
this->s_val = s[0];
this->e_val = s[s.length() - 1];
```

can be written more elegantly as:

```
s_val = s.first();
e_val = s.back();
```

btw. the copy ctor., assignemt operator and the destructor are redundent also.
the rule of three (or five, as C++11) says `*IF* you implement any of the copy ctor. assigment operator or the destructor - you need to implement them all.`
the question is, should you implement any of them at the first place? you don't have any dynamic allocation here, no shallow copying, and nothing special that needs special member functions (copy ctor. etc.).
you might as well delete the whole three and that will be the best case in your example.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out after a while, but still I can't overload it in such a way that I can call like `stuff s4 = "bcd"`, I have tried to change the argument to `const char *c` but still saying `error: conversion from ‘const char [4]’ to non-scalar type ‘stuff’ requested` any idea ?

Comment: what is the compiler you are using?

Comment: `g++ 4.8.2` it supports `c++11`

Comment: it should work , like here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d29a34a748cb5cb

Comment: yes, it's working when I say `A a; a = "abc";`, but it does not when I say `A a = "abc";`

Comment: ok leave it, I am posting this issue as a new question, thanks for your help.